# Determine differentiability in region

Tags: derivatives

Is there any test to indirectly determine if a function f is differentiable everywhere in a defined domain, for example $S=\{x|x\in\mathbb{R}\land x^2<4\}$? For example: let $f(x)=\frac{2}{x}$. We could calculate it's derivative $f'(x)=\frac{-2}{x^2}$, identify that the case $x^2=0$ causes indifferentiability in that point, and thereby conclude that when $x=0$ f isn't differentiable, and thus f isn't differentiable everywhere in the domain $S$ that we defined, but when this isn't of convenience, what could one do to determine differentiability?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: zhw, Of what? A test?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.  Please give an example "when this isn't of convenience"

Comment: Well, just some complicated formula where the points of indifferentiability isn't as trivial as it is in my example of f being 2/x. Take the gamma-function, and suppose we do not know where it is differentiable, and we'd like to know if it's differentiable everywhere in our domain S.

Comment: Let's say we have a function on some interval on the real line. If the function is not one covered by previous results, then we have to discover new means for testing differentiability. This happens all the time, for example in beginning calculus. You differentiate polynomials, cover the sum, product, quotient, chain rules etc. And then you confront the trig functions. There's nothing in your bag of tricks at that point that handles them. So you have to create new methods; with the trig functions this is usually done by an appeal to geometry.

Comment: With the gamma function, there is a technique known as "differentiation under the integral sign" that shows it is differentiable. Students are always looking for that "one thing" that will handle all situations. Often that simply doesn't exist.